# Display content at Bottom of last page when VF is rendered As pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I want to display content at the bottom of last page of pdf. This pdf is created by using tag renderdAs="pdf" for visualforce page.

Answer (score 1):

**This will work only for version 27 and below**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf"><head>
    <style>


        @page
                {
                   @bottom-left
                   {
                        content: element(footer);
                   }
                }
         div.footer 
                {
                    position: running(footer);
                }
       </style>
    </head>   
      <h1>Congratulations</h1>
      This is your new Page

      <div class="footer">Footer of the page</div>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that :

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
    <head>
    <style>
    @page {
       @bottom-right {
            content: "Page " counter(page);
        }
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      XXXXXXXX
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

But i don't know about on only the last page. It exist @page:last but doesn't seems to work

Comment: yes @page:last is not working and your solution prints at all pages.

Answer (score 0):

My footer is like this

```
<!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer">
            <p>Content</p>
            <div width="100%">
                <div style="float:left;border:1px solid;width:49%;">Test:</div>
                <div style="float:left;border:1px solid;width:25%;">Test </div>
                <div style="float:left;border:1px solid;width:25%;">Test </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

CSS which i used to made it render properly is

```
           @page {

                margin-bottom: 3.00cm;
                @bottom-center{
                 content: element(footer);
                }
            }

            body {
                position: relative;
            }

            div.footer {
                font-size:15px;
                display: block;
                border:1px solid;
                position: running(footer);
            }
```

And this works fine for me.
The solution proposed by @vivek is almost correct but not working in scenarios where i am using tabular layout.